# Jenkins cli usage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to figure out how to use the jenkins-cli, but am having no success.
At first it showed me ERROR : You must authenticate to access this jenkins
I've tried many different permutations of the parameters, but keep getting '"--username" is not a valid option' .
After a research i knew that --username and -password are no longer in use ! Is there any solution using SSH or Api key ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like this

`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://jenkins_url -auth USER:TOKEN`

You will get the jar file for your Jenkins at

`https://yourjenkinsurl/cli/`

Comment: Which means you have login via gui, generate a token under your user, then use that.

Comment: yes correct @IanW

Comment: The OP is having is rather basic ssue. Don't just jump to the final point, explain what he needs to do to get there. Provide a complete answer; that helps more people.

Comment: @IanW just read is question again and this is what I have answered

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, then you need only answer "yes, API key." to "Is there any solution using SSH or Api key ?". Or, you can say, yes, you can use an api key, this is the cli syntax, and this is how you generate/store the key". Then you have a complete answer that's useful to the OP and to others who may follow. 'cos you can assume if OP could not find the alternate cli option, probably did not find how to generate a key either.